# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, openai-gym

Edit: Problem Solved. Solution below.

Attempting to build a RL model to handle a task.
There are two inputs: x and y, both are measured on an int scale of 1 to 100.
Based on these two inputs there should be an output (action to take on, discrete(5)) and confidence.

Also, I'm very new to this territory. Please, feel free to ask me anything or correct me on something that seems downright dumb/wrong.

Here's my program (imports haven't been cleaned up....):

```
from abc import ABC
import gym
from tensorflow import keras
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
import random
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, metrics
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import os
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

steps = 10000
episodes = 100
score_requirement = 1000

class PlantEnv(Env, ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        # Actions = water: 0=(none), 1=(3 seconds), 2=(4 seconds), 3=(5 seconds), 4=(6 seconds)
        self.action_space = Discrete(5)

        # Starting Moisture
        moisture = 20 + random.randint(-10, 10)
        # Starting Chance of Rain
        chance_of_rain = 50 + random.randint(-50, 50)

        # Observations
        self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([0, 0]), high=np.array([100, 100]), dtype=np.int)
        self.state = moisture, chance_of_rain

        # Number of water steps left
        self.water_length = steps

    def step(self, action):
        # Action section
        water = 0

        if action == 1:
            water = 2
        elif action == 2:
            water = 3
        elif action == 3:
            water = 4
        elif action == 4:
            water = 5

        moisture, chance_of_rain = self.state

        moisture += (water * 5)
        self.water_length -= 1

        # Reward Section
        reward = 0
        if 40 <= moisture <= 60:
            reward = 2
        # If moisture is dry or wet
        elif 60 < moisture <= 80 or 20 <= moisture < 40:
            reward = 0.5
        # If moisture is really dry or really wet
        elif 80 < moisture <= 100 or 0 <= moisture < 20:
            reward = -1
        # If moisture is really dry or really wet
        elif 100 < moisture or moisture < 0:
            reward = -2

        # Check if shower is done
        if self.water_length <= 0:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False

        moistureLoss = random.randint(15, 25)
        moisture -= moistureLoss
        chance_of_rain = 50 + random.randint(-50, 50)
        xfactor = chance_of_rain + random.randint(-50, 50)
        if xfactor > 100:
            moisture += (10 + random.randint(0, 15))

        # Set placeholder for info
        info = {}

        # Save current state
        self.state = moisture, chance_of_rain

        # Return step information
        return self.state, reward, done, info

    def reset(self):
        # Reset test environment
        # Set starting moisture
        moisture = 50 + random.randint(-10, 10)
        # Set starting chance of rain array
        chance_of_rain = 50 + random.randint(-50, 50)
        self.state = moisture, chance_of_rain
        # Reset Test time
        self.water_length = steps
        return self.state


def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, 4)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
    return model


def build_agent(model):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=2,
                   nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn


# Create environment
env = PlantEnv()

accepted_scores = []
training_data = []
scores = []
good_episodes = 0

# Create episodes and initiate simulation
for episode in range(1, episodes + 1):
    observation = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0
    history = []
    prev_observation = []

    while not done:
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        if observation[0] > 100:
            action = 0
        elif observation[0] < 0:
            action = 4
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
        if len(prev_observation) > 0:
            history.append([prev_observation, action])
        prev_observation = observation

    if score >= score_requirement:
        good_episodes += 1
        accepted_scores.append(score)
        for data in history:
            if data[1] == 1:
                output = [1]
            else:
                output = [0]

            training_data.append([data[0], output])

    scores.append(score)

if len(accepted_scores) > 0:
    print("Average accepted score: ", np.mean(accepted_scores))
    print("Median accepted score : ", np.median(accepted_scores))
print("Episodes above accepted score of {}: {}/{}\n".format(score_requirement, good_episodes, episodes))

model = build_model()
model.summary()

dqn = build_agent(model)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

The first model gives this error when trying to dqn.fit:
**ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 2)**

The second model gives this error when trying to build_agent:
**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'**

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong or how to go about correcting it would be a massive help. I feel 95% confident that I have my environment setup correctly.

I initially went with the first model just to see if I could get the program to compile and work. Then, after further research, I built the second model because I understood that it was capable of giving me an action with a confidence rating. Getting errors at both turns.

Comment: Does the environment have a shape? I don't see an attribute for that available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model expects a 2D input but you defined it as 1D. Here is a working example:

```py
from abc import ABC
import gym
from tensorflow import keras
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
import random
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses, metrics
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import os
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

steps = 10000
episodes = 100
score_requirement = 1000

class PlantEnv(Env, ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        # Actions = water: 0=(none), 1=(3 seconds), 2=(4 seconds), 3=(5 seconds), 4=(6 seconds)
        self.action_space = Discrete(5)

        # Starting Moisture
        moisture = 20 + random.randint(-10, 10)
        # Starting Chance of Rain
        chance_of_rain = 50 + random.randint(-50, 50)

        # Observations
        self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([0, 0]), high=np.array([100, 100]), dtype=np.int)
        self.state = moisture, chance_of_rain

        # Number of water steps left
        self.water_length = steps

    def step(self, action):
        # Action section
        water = 0

        if action == 1:
            water = 2
        elif action == 2:
            water = 3
        elif action == 3:
            water = 4
        elif action == 4:
            water = 5

        moisture, chance_of_rain = self.state

        moisture += (water * 5)
        self.water_length -= 1

        # Reward Section
        reward = 0
        if 40 <= moisture <= 60:
            reward = 2
        # If moisture is dry or wet
        elif 60 < moisture <= 80 or 20 <= moisture < 40:
            reward = 0.5
        # If moisture is really dry or really wet
        elif 80 < moisture <= 100 or 0 <= moisture < 20:
            reward = -1
        # If moisture is really dry or really wet
        elif 100 < moisture or moisture < 0:
            reward = -2

        # Check if shower is done
        if self.water_length <= 0:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False

        moistureLoss = random.randint(15, 25)
        moisture -= moistureLoss
        chance_of_rain = 50 + random.randint(-50, 50)
        xfactor = chance_of_rain + random.randint(-50, 50)
        if xfactor > 100:
            moisture += (10 + random.randint(0, 15))

        # Set placeholder for info
        info = {}

        # Save current state
        self.state = moisture, chance_of_rain

        # Return step information
        return self.state, reward, done, info

    def reset(self):
        # Reset test environment
        # Set starting moisture
        moisture = 50 + random.randint(-10, 10)
        # Set starting chance of rain array
        chance_of_rain = 50 + random.randint(-50, 50)
        self.state = moisture, chance_of_rain
        # Reset Test time
        self.water_length = steps
        return self.state


def build_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1, 2)))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='linear'))
    return model


def build_agent(model):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=5,
                   nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn


# Create environment
env = PlantEnv()

accepted_scores = []
training_data = []
scores = []
good_episodes = 0

# Create episodes and initiate simulation
for episode in range(1, episodes + 1):
    observation = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0
    history = []
    prev_observation = []

    while not done:
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        if observation[0] > 100:
            action = 0
        elif observation[0] < 0:
            action = 4
        observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        score += reward
        if len(prev_observation) > 0:
            history.append([prev_observation, action])
        prev_observation = observation

    if score >= score_requirement:
        good_episodes += 1
        accepted_scores.append(score)
        for data in history:
            if data[1] == 1:
                output = [1]
            else:
                output = [0]

            training_data.append([data[0], output])

    scores.append(score)

if len(accepted_scores) > 0:
    print("Average accepted score: ", np.mean(accepted_scores))
    print("Median accepted score : ", np.median(accepted_scores))
print("Episodes above accepted score of {}: {}/{}\n".format(score_requirement, good_episodes, episodes))

model = build_model()
model.summary()

dqn = build_agent(model)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

Note that the `input_shape` 4 equals the number of `states` and the output nodes (2) equals the number of `actions`. You will have to change these parameters according to your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it. After adjusting my code, I now get this: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (1, 4) but got array with shape (1, 2)

Comment: The flatten layer, your output layer, and this parameter `nb_actions=5`

Comment: If I can add a semi-relevant question: when trying to use dqn.model.predict(np.array([30, 30])) I get this::: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1)

Comment: I don't understand what format I'm supposed to use to predict. Could you lend some insight?

Comment: Try `dqn.model.predict(np.expand_dims(np.array([30, 30]), axis=0))`

Comment: Almost the same error: ```ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 2)```

Comment: I need more information. Can you maybe post a new question? Because you do not have enough reputation to go to a chat-room.

Comment: [new post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855823/model-predict-valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-flatten-input)

Comment: Posted an answer.