# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape... but got the shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, openai-gym

When trying to implement a DQN with Tensorflow/Keras, on an openai-gym environment, I'm encountering this error:

`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have shape (1, 4) but got array with shape (1, 2))`

### What I have tried:

I did understand that my model gets the wrong input, **But I haven't yet figured out why, and how.**
Further, as can be seen, I have a Flatten layer, as recommended in other threads.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69855823/model-predict-valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-flatten-input) + [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841193/valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-input-to-have-2-dimensions)

Versions: `python 3.8.0`,`gym 0.26.2`,`protobuf 3.19.10`,`tensorflow 2.10.0`, My os is windows.

**This the relevant code:**

```
#importing al the relevant libraries...

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1', render_mode='human')
states = env.observation_space.shape[0]
actions = env.action_space.n

def build_model(states,actions):
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,states)))
   model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
   return model

model = build_model(states, actions)

def build_agent(model,actions):
   policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
   memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=1)
   dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy = policy,
                 nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
   return dqn

optimizerr = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
dqn = build_agent(model,actions)
dqn.compile(optimizer=optimizerr,metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

The error appears on the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from gym 0.26.2 to gym 0.17.1 solved the issue for me. That's the same version that was used in the youtube tutorial I'm assuming you were following.