# Error when checking input: expected dense_42_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 2, 2)

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

Im new to RL and python as well. Recently i try to create my on environment and when i try to run the program i got this error mention in the heading. I got this error when i try to build my model.
This is the environment i created

```
class EVEnv(Env):
def __init__(self):
    self.min_soc = 30
    self.max_soc = 80
    self.max_price = 5.0
    self.min_price = 0.5

    self.soc=45+random.randint(-10,10)
    self.price=3.5+random.randint(-3,3)
    def cost(self):
      cost= self.price * self.soc

    self.low = np.array([self.min_price, self.min_soc],dtype=np.float32)
    self.high = np.array([self.max_price, self.max_soc],dtype=np.float32)



    self.action_space = Discrete(2)
    self.observation_space =Box(self.low, self.high,dtype=np.float32)

   
def step(self, action):
    for self.soc in range (30,80):
       if self.soc==30 and self.soc==80:
          self.soc += action+1
       else:
          break
    #reward
    if cost>=15 and cost<=20: 
        reward =1 
    else: 
        reward = -1
    return reward
    
    if self.soc == 80: 
        done = True
    else:
        done = False
    info = {}
    return self.soc,self.price,reward,done,info

def reset(self):
    self.soc=45+random.randint(-10,10)
    self.price=3.5+random.randint(-3,3)
    return self.soc,self.price
```

And i try to create my model using keras.

```
estates = env.observation_space.shape
actions = env.action_space.n

def build_model(states, actions):
model = Sequential()  
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu', input_shape=states))
model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
return model
```

The summary of my model is
Model: "sequential_17"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

dense_42 (Dense)             (None, 24)                72

---

dense_43 (Dense)             (None, 24)                600

---

## dense_44 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 50

Total params: 722
Trainable params: 722
Non-trainable params: 0

And i try to build my agent using keras again.

```
def build_agent(model, actions):
policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=2)
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, 
              nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=10, target_model_update=1e-2)
return dqn
dqn = build_agent(model, actions)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=50000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

Since im new to this RL and python. I really don't know what to change. I tried changing the shape of the states but still it doesn't work. I would be really glad if you guys could help me.Thanks

Comment: Does this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841193/valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-input-to-have-2-dimensions) help you to solve this issue?